# Font changed on browser without changing any font settings?

Tags: browser, fonts

[image: Fonts on chrome and edge have changed to this]
After my computer shutdown unexpectedly (the battery fell out by accident) when I booted I was greeted with a something went wrong screen (windows 10) and my PIN was removed and asked for my password with which I logged in and this is how chrome and edge display webpages.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is for firefox.

[image]

This is for chrome. But unfortunately i'm not using the edge.